# reading up on ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

just a quick question, I have escaped the windoze world and need a guide / article / ebook that will give accurate info on how to use ubuntu.
There is a huge amount of internet garbage floating about, so need expert advice on where to get the info on starting out with ubuntu.
thanks
bri

Comment: one way would be browsing answered questions on this website tag-wise. you can start [here](http://askubuntu.com/tags)

Comment: You could check out the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here: http://tour.ubuntu.com/en/

Then peruse: http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/

Stick with Ubuntu official sites / links for the most ACCURATE info; not to say, other sources won't be as helpful!

Comment: thanks, The tour proved most interesting, will be perusing this for a while. there's a lot of info in the community, but not yet understand the syntax ect, working on it lol.

Comment: "Once you get past the "Windows", you can see the world"

Answer (score 3):

There is the Ubuntu Manual Project: http://ubuntu-manual.org/

The current version is for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Since you want to get started with Ubuntu, 14.04 **LTS** (Long Term Support) is recommendable. Here is why I like this guide:

- it is beginner friendly (e.g. plenty of screen shots)
- it guides you through the installation and configuration of the most important programs (e.g. Ubuntu itself, Firefox, printer setup, ...)
- it comes for free in pdf format
- it is available in plenty of languages in case you need it